# jquery call a variable based off other variables

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I have these variable defined:

```
var Counter1_1_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_2_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_3_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_4_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_5_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_6_yes = 0;
    var Counter1_7_yes = 0;
```

and I have this `$.each` statement inside an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/api/action/getAnswers?bullShitString=bullShitString",
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        success: function (data) {

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {

                Counter + value.questionnaireID + "_" + value.questionID + "_" + value.answer++;

                console.log(Counter1_1_yes);

            });


        }
    });
```

what I am trying to do, is in my each statement take the results from the ajax and add 1 to the variable.

I just get this error saying Counter is undefined. Is what I am trying to do possible?

Please Help.

Comment: And where `Counter` is defined?

Comment: @nicael I think his presumption is that `var ab` can be accessed from `"a" + "b"`. He's referring to the `Counter1_1_yes` variables up top.

Comment: You can't create/access variables with dynamic names like you could in PHP or mSL; however, you can do that with properties of objects in Javascript. If the variables are global, they're attached to the window object, in which case you could do `window[counter + "" +....]++`. I would highly suggest making an object like nicael suggested though.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The variable names can't be dynamic. For this purpose, I'd advice the object.

```
var Counter = {
    "1_1_yes":0,
    "1_2_yes":0,
    "1_3_yes":0,
    "1_4_yes":0,
    "1_5_yes":0,
    "1_6_yes":0,
    "1_7_yes":0
}

...

Counter[value.questionnaireID + "_" + value.questionID + "_" + value.answer]++;
console.log(Counter['1_1_yes']);
```